On the solution of these equations

Do not forget to see the Good News at the end of the problem.


This problem is linked to the previous one, up to a changes of coordinates. However, that question is actually about only the first three equations here. I add three new equations and hope that we can treat them as a system of 6 variables.

Let $(a,b,c,u,v,w)\in\mathbb{R}^6$,
$$
T := -a u -b v- c w,\quad S := T + u +v +w.
$$
Consider the following 6 equations:
$$
(1-a)S^2= u^2  -a T^2,
$$
$$
(1-b)S^2 =v^2 -b T^2,
$$
$$
(1-c)S^2=w^2 -c T^2,
$$
$$
\Big( (1-a)^2 S -a^2 T-u\Big)\Big((1-b)^2 S -b^2 T-v\Big)=\Big((1-a)(1-b)S-abT\Big)^2,
$$
$$
\Big( (1-a)^2 S -a^2 T-u\Big)\Big((1-c)^2 S -c^2 T-w\Big)=\Big((1-a)(1-c)S-acT\Big)^2,
$$
$$
\Big( (1-b)^2 S -b^2 T-v\Big)\Big((1-c)^2 S -c^2 T-w\Big)=\Big((1-b)(1-c)S-bcT\Big)^2.
$$
I want to find the solutions.

Original problem is:
Consider the homogeneous function
$$
f(u,v,w) = (u+v + w +T)^3 - (u^3 + v^3 + w^3 + T^3).
$$
I want to show if $x_0$ is a critical point $f$, that is, $\nabla f(x_0)=0$, then $\nabla^2 f(x_0)$ has rank 2, where $\nabla^2 f$ is the Hessian of $f$. So I get the six equation above.

How can I figure it out? Maybe the symmetry is helpful.

Good News: After expressing $a,b,c$ in terms of $(T,S,u,v,w)$ from the first three equations, and then put them into the left three equations to get a system of 4 equations on $(T, u, v, w)$. Mathematica tells me that the non-zero solutions of the original 6 equations must have the form
$$
(1,0,0,u,0,0)\ \ \mbox{or}\ \ (0,1,0,0,v,0)\ \ \mbox{or} \  \  (0,0,1,0,0,w).
$$
In fact, the four new equations for $(T,u,v,w)$ now are:
$$
(eq.1)\ \ S(v(T^2-u^2)^2+ u(T^2-v^2)^2)+ (u^2-v^2)^2 ST = uv(T^2-S^2)^2+ T((u^2-S^2)^2 v + (v^2-S^2)^2 u)
$$
$$
(eq.2)\ \ S(w(T^2-u^2)^2+ u(T^2-w^2)^2)+ (u^2-w^2)^2 ST = uw(T^2-S^2)^2+ T((u^2-S^2)^2 w + (w^2-S^2)^2 u)
$$
$$
(eq.3)\ \ S(w(T^2-v^2)^2+ v(T^2-w^2)^2)+ (v^2-w^2)^2 ST = vw(T^2-S^2)^2+ T((v^2-S^2)^2 w + (w^2-S^2)^2 v)
$$
$$
(eq.4) \ \ S^3 = T^3 + u^3 + v^3 + w^3,\ \ \mbox{where} \ S= T+u+v+w.
$$
You can only work on them, Mathematica tells me the real solution of this system must take the form, e.g. [$T=-u$, $v=w=0$] or [$T=w=0$, $u=-v$] (other solution are similar by symmetry).


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Continuing the OP's system of four equations in four variables $(u,v,w,T)$, we find that due to the symmetries of the system, then two of variables $(w,T)$ can be expressed in terms of the other two, namely,
$$uv(u + v)(uv + uZ + vZ)+ (u^2 + uv + v^2)(u + v + Z)Z^2=0$$
where $(w,T)$ are any TWO distinct roots of the cubic in $Z$ and found using the resultant function of Mathematica.
Let $u = p+q$ and $v = p-q$, then the discriminant of the cubic is,
$$D = (3p^2 + q^2)(25p^6 + 25p^4q^2 + 115p^2q^4 + 27q^6)$$
For real $(p,q) \neq 0$, then $D$ is always positive, implying the cubic never has all roots real. Therefore, one of the $(w,T)$ has to be a complex root, so the OP has found all non-zero real roots of the system if we also include $uvw(u+v+w)=0$.

Example 1:
For a simple case, let $u=1,v=1$, then the cubic becomes,
$$2 + 4Z + 6Z^2 + 3Z^3 = 0$$
with three roots for $k=0,1,2,$
$$Z_k = \frac{-2-10^{1/3}\,\zeta_3^k}3$$
and root of unity $\zeta_3 = \frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}2$ so, $Z_1, Z_2, Z_3 = -1.38481,\, -0.30759 - 0.62193 i,\,  -0.30759 + 0.62193 i$. Then $(w,T)$ is any two of these three roots. For aesthetics, I prefer $(u,v,w)$ to be real and $T$ to be any of the two complex cubic roots $Z_k$.

Example 2: (Casus Irreducibilis)
The above cubic's discriminant is always positive. The OP asked about discriminants. For clarity, and for an example of a cubic with a negative discriminant so yields three real roots,
$$x^3+x^2-2x-1=0$$
hence,
$$x_1 = 2\cos\big(\tfrac{2\pi}7\big) = -\tfrac13+\tfrac13\,\alpha^{1/3}+\tfrac13\,\beta^{1/3} \approx 1.24697$$
$$x_2 = 2\cos\big(\tfrac{4\pi}7\big) = -\tfrac13+\tfrac13\,\alpha^{1/3}\,\zeta_3+\tfrac13\,\beta^{1/3}\,\zeta_3^2 \approx -0.44504$$
$$x_3 = 2\cos\big(\tfrac{8\pi}7\big) = -\tfrac13+\tfrac13\,\alpha^{1/3}\,\zeta_3^2+\tfrac13\,\beta^{1/3}\,\zeta_3^4 \approx -1.80193$$
where $\alpha = \frac{7\left(1-3\sqrt{\color{red}{-3}}\right)}2,\,$ $\beta = \tfrac{7\left(1+3\sqrt{\color{red}{-3}}\right)}2,\,$ and $\,\zeta_3 = \frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}2.$

Great, can you explain more about the appear of the first equation in your answer? Do you mean that was found by resultant function of Mathematica? I'm not very familiar with this concept.

@cbi You were close to the solution already. Since the system is very symmetric wrt $(u,v,w)$ use the Resultant function to eliminate T from eq.4 from either eq.1,2,3. The command is Factor[Resultant[Poly1, Poly2, T]]. Make sure there is no equal sign in the Poly so subtract the LHS of your equations 1-4.

Can I derive this eq by myself (without computer)?

@cbi By pen and paper? Theoretically, yes. But you have a system of NON-linear equations, and it is hard to apply Gaussian elimination. Whenever I have a non-linear system of $n$ equations in $n$ unknowns, I use the resultant function repeatedly until I have a single equation in one or two unknowns.

I'm still a little confused, why I learn from webside that "the discriminant is positive if the roots are three distinct real numbers"?

@cbi That's a well-known ambiguity in the literature. Historically, complex numbers were discovered in the context of "cubic casus irreducibilis", when one has to take the square root of a negative number.  This cubic then yield three real numbers. In the site you linked, the discriminant is $D = -4p^3-27q^2$. But if you ask Wolfram to solve the depressed cubic, then you get $D =  3(4p^3+27q^2)$ as in this example. One just has to be careful with signs. P.S. I added an example for clarity.

@cbi I also gave an example of the "casus irreducibilis" and how getting the square root of a negative discriminant yields three real roots.

Thanks! One more question, I just try to use mathematica to compute Resultant[eq.3, eq.4, T] and get the desired formula for $w$ (in your equation $Z$ is replaced by $w$). Then what should I do next to get similar equation for $T$?

@cbi Call the cubic in w as cubic_w. Then command is Factor[Resultant[eq.3, cubic_w, w]] which yields cubic_T. But if you look at the coefficients, they are the same. Thus you know that $(w,T)$ are distinct roots of the same cubic.

Do you mean eq.1 and eq.2 are not be used?

I tried Factor[Resultant[eq.3, cubic_w, w]], but I got an extra factor (very long) except the equation of $T$.

@cbi Do you mean "except" or "in addition to"? Because I just tried it again and easily found the equation of $T$. Resultants usually produce extra factors. To find the correct one, compare Factor[Resultant[eq.3, cubic_w, w]]  and Factor[Resultant[eq.4, cubic_w, w]]. The common factor will be the correct one.

@cbi Now you know about Resultants, try experimenting. You can use eq.1, eq.2, eq.3, but because of the symmetries of the system, Factor[Resultant[eq.1, eq.4, T]], Factor[Resultant[eq.2, eq.4, T]], and Factor[Resultant[eq.3, eq.4, T]] yield the same cubic in w. This is not always the case with a random system of equations.

Oh, I see. "The common factor will be the correct one." comes from the resultants theory?

Yeah, I mean I found the resultant is the equation of $T$ multiply by a extremely long term.

@cbi Yes, the common factor will satisfy the system. Resultants are just a generalization of linear elimination. P.S. It is not encouraged to have long discussions in the comments and I'm sure I've given you enough information to continue your research on your own. Cheers.
